# How to get string if length is more than 50?

Tags: java, string

In java how to split a string value, if >50 then the string after the last succeeding **comma** should be assigned to another String.

Eg:

```
String test = "ASDFGHJKLPOIUYTRE YUIOOPPKMABJFD AJDJDJDJD, DJDJDJD DJDJDJ, JDJDJD UYUYUAU JKBFDKJBDKJJK";
```

the above string's length is 88.
after 50th character @59th "," is presented so string should be split with the last succeeding "**comma**" and the output should be as follows:

ASDFGHJKLPOIUYTRE YUIOOPPKMABJFD AJDJDJDJD, DJDJDJD DJDJDJ,

JDJDJD UYUYUAU JKBFDKJBDKJJK

thanks in advance!!!

I have tried as follows:

```
if(add1.length() > 50){
            for(int i=50;i<add1.length();i++){
                if(add1.charAt(i)== ','){
                    add2 = add1.substring((i+1),add1.length());
                    add1 = add1.substring(0,i);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: do a loop for each character, count each loop, and while that, save each letter into string A. If counter is > 50 && actual character == ",", save the rest of the loop to string B

Comment: This smells of homework from km (or miles)

Comment: What if last comma is before 50th character but string length is >50? Should you split?

Comment: @Pshemo, if thats the case no need to split

Comment: This is where you must actually write code.  The two-argument version of indexOf, as suggested by Quirliom can be quite helpful, though one can get along without it if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29) method of strings to find the next comma, then manually splitting:

```
if(test.length() > 50){
    int comma = test.indexOf(',', 50);
    if(comma >= 0){

        //Bit before comma
        String partOne = test.substring(0, comma);

        //Bit after comma
        String partTwo = test.substring(comma);

        //Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: Typically one will want to remove any leading blanks on the second substring (and possibly trailing blanks on the first substring).  `trim()` is good for that.

Comment: how to do the same for last comma before 50.

Comment: off the top of my head, you could try splitting at the index `test.substring(0, 50).lastIndexOf(',');` but there is probably a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try [subString()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm), [indexOf()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm), [replace()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm)

```
if(test.length() > 50)
        {
            System.out.println(test.substring(test.lastIndexOf(",") + 1, test.length()).replace(",", ""));
        }
```

Comment: i think OP is asking to split after 50th character

Comment: Ya i know but he mentioned the following "so string should be split with the last succeeding "comma" "

Answer (score 0):

```java
String someString = "";
    int lastCommaPosition = someString.lastIndexOf(",");
    if(lastCommaPosition > 50){
        String firstPart = someString.substring(0,lastCommaPosition +1);
        String secondPart = someString.substring(lastCommaPosition);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Java version
public class StrSub {

    private String s = "ASDFGHJKLPOIUYTRE YUIOOPPKMABJFD AJDJDJDJD, DJDJDJD DJDJDJ, JDJDJD UYUYUAU JKBFDKJBDKJJK";

    private void compute() {
        int i = 50, p = 0, len = s.length();
        String s1, s2;
        for (i = 50; i < len; i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == ',') {
                p = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(p);
        s1 = s.substring(0, p+1);
        s2 = s.substring(p+1);

        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StrSub s = new StrSub();        
        s.compute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Java version is coming soon. I used JavaScript for quick prototyping.

Comment: Then I would suggest wait, and answer in Java, rather than giving a quick answer that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @kadaj you have done it in JS i just used your logic,no worry I will delete my answer,I was wrting your name in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
String test = "ASDFGHJKLPOIUYTRE YUIOOPPKMABJFD AJDJDJDJD, DJDJDJD DJDJDJ, JDJDJD UYUYUAU JKBFDKJBDKJJK";
int index = 0;
if (test.length() > 50) {
    index = test.indexOf(",", 50);
}
String firstString = test.substring(0, index + 1);
String secondString = test.substring(index + 1);
System.out.println(firstString);
System.out.println(secondString);
```

Comment: Why are you creating multiple String objects for this. Try to reduce

Comment: just to distinguish the output so that it can be easily understood. otherwise its not needed

Comment: Its ok. Because String is immutable it creates more memory in heap. For your remembrance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
int index = 0;
String[] out= new String[test.length()/50]();

for(int i=50, j=0; test.length() > 50 ; j++){

if(test.length>i){
      index = test.indexOf(",",i);
}
out[j] = test.subString(0,index);
test = test.subString(index+1, test.length());
}

// Cover the boundary condition
if(test.length() > 0){
out[j] = test;
```